# Laravel diff($collection) throws error

Tags: database, laravel, collections, diff, pivot-table

I tried using the diff-Function to get all items that don't relate to a certain item in a many-to-many relation using pivot tables.

Here's what I came up with:
I want to use the `diff($collection)` function but I always get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Collection::__construct() must
>   be of the type array, object given, called in
>   ***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
>   on line 157 and defined

See an example of the function here: http://www.neontsunami.com/post/new-collection-methods-in-laravel-4-1

I added the following two lines to my providers array in app.php

```
'Illuminate\Support\Collection',
'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection',
```

This is my code in `User.php`:

```
public function scopeNotProject($query, $project_id)
    {   $all_users = Users::all();
        $participants = Project::find($project_id)->users;
        $nonparticipants = $all_users->diff($participants);
        return $nonparticipants;
    }
```

and my View:

```
@foreach(User::notProject($project_id)->get() as $nonparticipant)
                  <option value="{{ $nonparticipant->id }}">{{ $nonparticipant->firstname . " " . $nonparticipant->lastname }}</option>
@endforeach
```

As far as I can see, the passed item should be a Collection and not an array(?). I'm new to laravel so ANY help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first parameter need to be an array, it is telling you. And because users is a collection this is an object and you cannot compare an array with an object.

Change

```
$participants = Project::find($project_id)->users;
```

to

```
$participants = Project::find($project_id)->users->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem :) :

```
@foreach (User::all()->diff(Project::find($project_id)->users) as $nonparticipant)
    <option value="{{ $nonparticipant->id }}">{{ $nonparticipant->firstname . " " . $nonparticipant->lastname }}</option>
@endforeach
```